# Profiling script for gathering a lot of data from an API

Tags: python, performance

I wrote a script which is supposed to be making requests to an API to gather a lot of data. There is a limit on requests that I can make: about 30 000 in 8 hours otherwise, I will get banned for a significant time. Each object I get from the API can be identified uniquely with a hash. Each API call returns me some data I need and also the hash of the next object I need to get. So I start with some hash I have, make a request, parse the result and obtain the hash of the next object. Repeat. I also log the time of each 20th request I make, recording the time to keep track of the number of the requests I made in last 8 hours.

Here is my code:

```
import ujson
import requests
import time
import os
import cProfile

# 'logs' has all the requests in the last 8 hours


# the snippet of code which does all of the hard work
for i in range(len(logs) * requests_per_log, maximum_requests):  # to stay in max requests range

    r = requests.get(url + current_hash)
    block = ujson.loads(r.text)  # use ujson because it is faster
    block_timestamp_str = format_timestamp(block['time'])
    block_index_str = str(block['block_index'])

    # only log each 20th request
    if i % 20 == 0:
        f_logs.write(str(time.time()) + '\n')  # log the time when the request was made
    f = open('data/' + block_index_str + "__" + block_timestamp_str, "w+")
    block_string = parse_transactions_in_block(block)
    current_hash = block['prev_block']
    f.write(block_string)
    f.close()
    # record the hash the script stopped at
    f_current_hash.write(current_hash)


# some of the functions it uses:

def parse_transactions_in_block(block):
    block_string = ''
    for transaction in block['tx']:
        block_string += str(transaction['time']) + ',' + str(transaction['tx_index']) \
                        + ',' + str(calc_total_input(transaction)) + '\n'
    return block_string


def calc_total_input(transaction):
    total_input = 0
    for input in transaction['out']:
        total_input += input['value']


# this is the time format I was asked to keep my data in  

def format_timestamp(unix_time):
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S', time.gmtime(unix_time))
```

There is a lot of data to go through, so I want it to be as fast as possible and my previous iterations took a while to run. I am running it on Google Compute Engine using a Linux distribution. Any ideas how I can make this work faster? I don't have enough experience on concurrent computing in Python, so I am just looking for a way of optimizing what I have, without concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the improvements to the current "synchronous" approach:

- maintain an instance of the [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) - this would improve performance:

  > ..if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
  >   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
  >   performance increase

  ```
  with requests.Session() as session:
      r = session.get(url + current_hash)
  ```
- use the [`.json()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) to get the JSON object directly out of a response (you would first need to adjust the "json model" to use `ujson`, [source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1595)):

  ```
  requests.models.json = ujson
  # ...
  block = r.json()
  ```
- don't open/close files in the main loop - collect the data into memory and dump after. If the data does not fit the memory, use pagination - write to the output file(s) in chunks.
- the `parse_transactions_in_block()` may be rewritten using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

  ```
  def parse_transactions_in_block(block):
      return ''.join("{time},{index},{total}\n".format(time=transaction['time'],
                                                       index=transaction['tx_index'],
                                                       total=calc_total_input(transaction))
                     for transaction in block['tx'])
  ```
- the `calc_total_input()` can be rewritten using `sum()`:

  ```
  def calc_total_input(transaction):
      return sum(input['value'] for input in transaction['out'])
  ```
- try the [`PyPy` interpreter](http://pypy.org/) - can give you a performance boost with no changes to the code (well, I doubt `ujson` will still work, but [`simplejson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson) might be a good alternative in this case)

That said, given the information provided in the question, the bottleneck feels to still be the *blocking nature of the script*. See if you can switch to, for example, [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](https://scrapy.org/), or use the [`grequests` library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).